# In objective-c is it possible to extend a delegate method instead of replacing it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

Let's say I'm making a custom delegate for the Class

GMSMapView using the type GMSMapViewDelegate

One of the methods is

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker {
```

Now let's say instead of replacing this method, I just wanted to call

```
NSLog("This method ran")
```

When the method was activated.

Is it possible to simply extend the default behavior of this method with the NSLog functionality?

Comment: Your question have a couple of issues, a delegate is kind of a contract you need to follow, a delegation pattern is basically an entrance point, and you can use this, (of course depending of the class design) to either extend or identify a state of the object. If you can give an example of what you want to achieve, perhaps I can provide a workaround.

Comment: "extend the default behavior of this method" What do you mean by the default behavior? There is no default behavior for a protocol method.

Comment: Indeed delegates are built on protocols which just define an interface and no implementation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement your own delegate class.
2. Have a delegate in that class.
3. Implement each of the delegate methods to log and call your delegate's delegate.
4. Profit.   Actually, be prepared to deal with `@optional` methods;  you might need to *not* call through automatically if the original delegate didn't implement 'em.
5. Set the delegate of the class to your delegate, then set the delegate of your delegate to the original delegate.